# Can't authenticate to Azure DevOps with Personal Access Token from ASP.NET app using Windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that uses the TFS client libraries to access an on-premises TFS server. The app uses Windows authentication on a Windows domain and the default credentials are used in the connection to TFS.

I need to extend the app to also access an Azure DevOps organization. I tried creating a VSSConnecton object and using a personal access token (PAT) like this:

```
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(accountUri, new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, personalAccessToken));
WorkItemTrackingHttpClient witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
```

The PAT is not used though. The user's Windows credentials are passed thru regardless of which overload I use in the VssBasicCredential method.

Even though the Azure AD is being sync'd from the Windows AD domain, the user is seen as a different object and doesn't have access to Azure DevOps. Because the Azure AD user and the local Windows user have the same username (fname.lname@domain.com) I also can't add the local Windows user as an external user in Azure.

Is there a way to authenticate to Azure DevOps using a PAT (or other alternative credentials) from an ASP.NET app using Windows authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up not being an issue with the code at all. The code as listed above DOES work even when connected to a Windows AD domain. While testing, I was connected to the network via VPN and there was apparently some issue with that connection that was causing the authentication to not work.

Comment: If is solved, you could mark it as an answer to close this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Try to authenticate with Azure AD credentials:

```
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(accountUri, new VssAadCredential(username, password));
```

Comment: This initially didn't work either; however it was because of a network configuration. Once that was resolved, both your answer and the original code in my question worked correctly.

Comment: Great! The main thing is that the authentication works :)